# Extract consecutive numbers to form ranges in scala list

Tags: list, scala, range

i have a scala list of tuples,

```
val stdLis:List[(String,Int)]=null
```

I need to combine the consecutive integers in the list to form ranges. The final result only needs ranges of integers from the list. The following approach leaves the non-consecutive numbers. But i **need to form ranges for the consecutive numbers and also retain non consecutive numbers** in the final list.

```
def mergeConsecutiveNum(lis:List[(String,Int)])={ 
 var lisBuf = new ListBuffer[(String,Int)]
    val newRanges = new ListBuffer[(Int,Int)]()
    if(lis.size>1)
    lis.sliding(2).foreach{i=>
      if(i(0)._2+1 == i(1)._2)
        lisBuf.appendAll(i)
      else{
        //println(lisBuf)
        if(lisBuf.size>1) {
          newRanges.append((lisBuf.head._2, lisBuf.last._2))
          newRanges.append((i(0)._2,i(1)._2))
        }
        lisBuf.clear()
      }
    }else
    newRanges.append((lis.head._2,0))
    newRanges
}
```

for example:

```
val lis = List(("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("d",4),("e",6),("f",7),("g",9))
```

it should give

```
lis((1,4),(6,7),(9,0))
```

Comment: "also retain non consecutive numbers" WHat does this mean? If there's an odd number of sublists produce (lastvalue, 0) in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't exactly know what you are asking. 
Your code does not return anything. 
Anyways, assuming that you need to merge two consecutive numbers in the list and create a range of list based on those numbers, here is something you can try

```
List(("", 5),("", 10),("", 6),("", 10)).map(_._2).grouped(2).map(ele => ele(0) to ele(1)).toList
List(Range(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Range(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```